# Detailed class based view in aiohttp

Tags: python-3.6, aiohttp

I'm trying to make a class based view in aiohttp. I'm following the [doc](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#view). All goes good but I can't find a way to make detailed views.

```
from aiohttp import web


class MyView(web.View):

    async def get(self):
        resp = await get_response(self.request)
        return resp

    async def post(self):
        resp = await post_response(self.request)
        return resp

    app.router.add_view('/view', MyView)
```

This code will produce two endpoints:

```
POST /view
GET /view
```

But how to add the `GET /view/:pk:` using the class-based views? I know that I can make it manually, adding to the router without the class-based views but I'm looking for a way to use it here.

**UPD:**
The goal is to generate the URLs like

```
"""
POST /view      # creation
GET /view       # a full list
GET /view/:id:  # detailed view

"""



from aiohttp import web


class MyView(web.View):

    async def get(self):
        resp = await get_response(self.request)
        return resp

    async def post(self):
        resp = await post_response(self.request)
        return resp

    async def detailed_get(self):
        resp = await post_response(self.request)
        return resp


    app.router.add_view('/view', MyView)
```

Or at least get the URLs like:

```
POST /view     # creation
GET /view/:id: # detailed view
```

Comment: Use `app.router.add_view('/view/{pk}', MyView)`

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov, it's not exactly what I want. I'll make an update in the question

Comment: Well, updated question has to distinct URLs, you need two distinct routes for it.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov yes, I understand how to make it with two routes. The question is 'Is it possible to generate the routes like this using class-based views?' I supposed that it's something like a Django's mixins.

Comment: Say again the view handles the single URL pattern only. URL with trailing slash is different from URL without it by RFC. Thus you need to add the view twice under different patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating the additional behavior on class-based view add route decorator to View.

```py
from aiohttp import web

routes = web.RouteTableDef()


@routes.view('/ert/{name}')
@routes.view('/ert/')
class MyView(web.View):

    async def get(self):
        return web.Response(text='Get method')

    async def post(self):
        return web.Response(text='Post method')
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted to have, but it's the closest one!